# PHP: Why won't my PDO prepared statement insert data into my table?

Tags: php, stored-procedures, pdo, transactions, prepared-statement

```
PHP 5.6.11
MySQL 5.6
CentOS 7 (with MySQL 5.6)
```

Note: This is not my literal code. I have abstracted certain parts. No errors are given upon execution. No data is written to the `contact` table.

I have a table named contact...

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `database`.`contact`(
`contact_id` VARCHAR(32) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'Contact ID',
`firstname` VARCHAR(30) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'First name.',
`lastname` VARCHAR(30) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'Last name.',
`email` VARCHAR(128) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'E-mail address.',
`phone` VARCHAR(12) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Telephone number',
`country_code` VARCHAR(7) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Country code number',
`extension` VARCHAR(5) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Telephone extension',
`company` VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Company affiliation.',
`address` VARCHAR(100) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Street Address.',
`city` VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'City.',
`state` VARCHAR(6) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'State.',
`zip` VARCHAR(10) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Zip code.',
`country` VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Country.',
`phone_type` ENUM('Cellular', 'Landline') CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'Telephone type',
`time_to_contact` ENUM('A.M.', 'P.M.') CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'Morning or Afternoon',
`contact_pref` ENUM('Email', 'Phone', 'Mail') CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'Contact preference',
`job_location` VARCHAR(100) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Jobsite location',
`news_subscribed` ENUM('N', 'Y') CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'Contact subscribed to newsletter.',
`news_subs_token` VARCHAR(60) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'Used when subscribing to the newsletter.',
`news_unsub_token` VARCHAR(60) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'Used when unsubscribing to the newsletter.',
`message_time` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'Time of last message.',
CONSTRAINT `contactconstr01` PRIMARY KEY (`contact_id`))
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 DEFAULT COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci COMMENT 'Contacts (external) table.';
```

...and I want to use this stored procedure, with embedded prepared statement, to insert records.

```
   CREATE DEFINER = 'blahfoobar'@'localhost' 
PROCEDURE `database`.add_contact_sp(
            IN contact_id VARCHAR(32),
            IN firstname VARCHAR(30),
            IN lastname VARCHAR(30),
            IN email VARCHAR(128),
            IN phone VARCHAR(12),
            IN country_code VARCHAR(7),
            IN extension VARCHAR(5),
            IN company VARCHAR(50),
            IN address VARCHAR(100),
            IN city VARCHAR(50),
            IN st VARCHAR(6),
            IN zip VARCHAR(10),
            IN country VARCHAR(50),
            IN phone_type VARCHAR(8),
            IN time_to_contact VARCHAR(4),
            IN contact_preference VARCHAR(5),
            IN job_location VARCHAR(100),
            IN news_subscribed VARCHAR(1),
            IN news_sub_token VARCHAR(60),
            IN news_unsub_token VARCHAR(60))
  COMMENT 'Insert new contact record.'
 LANGUAGE SQL
DETERMINISTIC
 MODIFIES SQL DATA
      SQL SECURITY DEFINER  
    BEGIN
          SET @id      = contact_id;
          SET @fName   = firstname;
          SET @lName   = lastname;
          SET @eMail   = email;
          SET @p       = phone;
          SET @cc      = country_code;
          SET @ext     = extension;
          SET @comp    = company;
          SET @addr    = address;
          SET @c       = city;
          SET @s       = st;
          SET @zCode   = zip;
          SET @coun    = country;
          SET @pType   = phone_type;
          SET @ttc     = time_to_contact;
          SET @cPref   = contact_preference;
          SET @jLoc    = job_location;
          SET @news    = news_subscribed;
          SET @nSubT   = news_subs_tokens;
          SET @nUnsubT = news_unsub_token; 

          PREPARE `insert_contact_stmt` FROM
                  'INSERT INTO `contact`
                   VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';
          EXECUTE `insert_contact_stmt` USING @id, @fName, @lName, @eMail, @p, @cc, @ext, @comp, @addr, @c, @s, @zCode, @coun, @pType, @ttc, @cPref, @jLoc, @news, @nSubT, @nUnsubT;
          DEALLOCATE PREPARE `insert_contact_stmt`;
      END//
```

The security settings look like....

```
GRANT INSERT ON TABLE `database`.`contact` TO 'blahfoobar'@'localhost';
GRANT SELECT ON TABLE `database`.`contact` TO 'blahfoobar'@'localhost';
GRANT UPDATE ON TABLE `database`.`contact` TO 'blahfoobar'@'localhost';
GRANT DELETE ON TABLE `database`.`contact` TO 'blahfoobar'@'localhost';

GRANT EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE `database`.`add_contact_sp` TO 'blahfoobar'@'localhost', 'blahblahblah'@'localhost';
```

...where 'blahblahblah'@'localhost' represents that actual user that makes the connection to the MySQL server during the PDO connection phase (not shown).

My PHP, a protected method of sub-class `Contact` (super-class `Person`) looks like the following, where the `$db` object near the top is a wrapper object for a PDO connection.

```
protected function insert()
{   
    try
    {            
        $this->db->startTransaction();

        $stmt = $this->db->prepare('add_contact_sp(:contact_id, :firstname, :lastname, :email, :phone, :country_code, :extension, :company, :address, :city, :state, :zip, :country, :phone_type, :time_to_contact, :contact_pref, :job_location, :news_subscribed, :news_sub_token, :news_unsub_token');

        if($stmt instanceof PDOStatement)
        {
            //Where $stmt is passed by reference.

            $this->db->bindParam($stmt, ':contact_id', $this->id);
            $this->db->bindParam($stmt, ':firstname', $this->firstname);
            $this->db->bindParam($stmt, ':lastname', $this->lastname);
            $this->db->bindParam($stmt, ':email', $this->email);
            $this->db->bindParam($stmt, ':phone', $this->phone);
            $this->db->bindParam($stmt, ':country_code', $this->countryCode);
            $this->db->bindParam($stmt, ':extension', $this->extension);
            $this->db->bindParam($stmt, ':company', $this->company);
            $this->db->bindParam($stmt, ':address', $this->address);
            $this->db->bindParam($stmt, ':city', $this->city);
            $this->db->bindParam($stmt, ':state', $this->state);
            $this->db->bindParam($stmt, ':zip', $this->zip);
            $this->db->bindParam($stmt, ':country', $this->country);
            $this->db->bindParam($stmt, ':phone_type', $this->phoneType);     
            $this->db->bindParam($stmt, ':time_to_contact', $this->timeToContact);
            $this->db->bindParam($stmt, ':contact_pref', $this->contactPref);
            $this->db->bindParam($stmt, ':job_location', $this->jobLocation);
            $this->db->bindParam($stmt, ':news_subscribed', $this->newsSubscribed);
            $this->db->bindParam($stmt, ':news_sub_token', $this->newsSubToken);
            $this->db->bindParam($stmt, ':news_unsub_token', $this->newsUnsubToken);  

            if(!$stmt->execute())
            {
                print_r($stmt->errorInfo(), true);  //Just for debugging.
            }
            else
            {
                $this->db->commit();  
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            throw new PDOException("Failed to prepare the PDO statement.");
        }
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        $this->db->rollback();
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

No errors. No data is written to the database. Nothing. Is it possible to use PDO transactions with MySQL stored procedures that have embedded prepared statements?

Here are my database connection options as requested.

```
$options  = [
                PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
                PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
                PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'utf8mb4\' COLLATE \'utf8mb4_unicode_ci\''
            ];
```

Comment: May I suggest that you look into writing [a minimal complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and giving a clear problem statement: what did you expect to happen, what happened instead. Right now, there's so much detail it's hard to find the actual question.

Comment: @IMSoP It's just a table. Then, a stored procedure to insert a record into that table. Next, the security settings. Finally, the PHP where the stored procedure is called. Looked upon like this, this is not a complex presentation. If you've seen one, you've seen them all. Still, I get no errors. Strange.

Comment: @AnthonyRutledge Do you think there could be an issue with trying to bind too many parameters?

Comment: @Melinda I don't know if too many parameters could be a problem, but that's certainly something that simplifying the example could help you rule out. Make a simpler table, and a simpler procedure; eliminate the complexity of the PHP class hierarchy by writing a test script using nothing but PDO; try executing the statement with and without transactions, with and without preparing; and so on. Note which change makes it break. This is the essence of debugging - narrowing down the problem. Once you do that, you'll either find the answer yourself, or have a much clearer question to ask here.

Comment: I can say that reading from the database works just fine (using PDO prepared statements and calling MySQL stored procedures with embedded prepared statements).

Answer (score 1):

There are other errors in your PDO::prepare statement, but this is the first one. You are missing a parenthesis at the end of your PREPARE statement. It should look like this. The rest have to do with the order of your parameters and binding. You have twenty parameters. Make sure they are in the correct, corresponding order. Right now, they are not.

```
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare('add_contact_sp(:contact_id, :firstname, :lastname, :email, :phone, :country_code, :extension, :company, :address, :city, :state, :zip, :country, :phone_type, :time_to_contact, :contact_pref, :job_location, :news_subscribed, :news_sub_token, :news_unsub_token)');
```